# Missing eigenvector in differential equation - Calculating a fundamental system

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this differential equation:
$$y'=Ay \text{ with } A=\begin{pmatrix}3&2\\-2&-1\end{pmatrix}$$
I have calculated the eigenvalues and found $\lambda_{1/2}=1$

Now if i replace lambda with the eigenvalue in the following matrix i am finding an eigenvector:

$$\begin{pmatrix}3-1&2\\-2&-1-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2&2\\-2&-2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2&2\\0&0\end{pmatrix} => y=1 , x=-y$$
Hence: Eigenvector $\upsilon_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\end{pmatrix}$

My Problem is, that i cannot find the second eigenvector. I need a second one for creating a fundamental system.

How can i do that?

Comment: Have you learned about Generalized Eigenvectors? For example, http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT2440/v11/undervisningsmateriale/genvectors.pdf or https://www.math.upenn.edu/~moose/240S2013/slides7-31.pdf,

Comment: not really. at least it means nothing to me at this moment but i can google it and try learning if you say it is helpful :-)

Comment: ok i will try. Thank you so much

Comment: Here is another one: http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~spl/old_courses/304_fall_2008/handouts/jordan.pdf (see Example 2). For this deficient matrix, you should get a generalized eogenvector of $$\upsilon_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}-\dfrac{1}{2}\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to solve the system above, there are other ways that do not require generalized eigenvectors. For example, in your specific case above, letting $y=(y_1,y_2)$, adding the first and the second row of the matrix gives $$\dot{y}_1+\dot{y}_2=y_1+y_2,$$
which gives $y_1+y_2=e^t+c$, and then solve a linear differential equation to find $y_1$ and $y_2$.